# mysql Scheduled Event syntax error

Tags: mysql

Hello i want to delete my sql table row every one hour.

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `money`
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY  1 HOUR

DO
    BEGIN

    DELETE FROM `money` WHERE `payed` = 'processing' AND `payed2` = 'processing';

    END
```

I get this error :

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 8

Comment: try to remove \`s around \`payed\` and \`payed2\`

Comment: @Alp you're guessing, and what you suggest is not relevant to the problem.

Comment: nop didnt work but what  Uueerdo said below it worked thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `money`
ON SCHEDULE EVERY  1 HOUR
DO
BEGIN

    DELETE FROM `money` WHERE `payed` = 'processing' AND `payed2` = 'processing';

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I am stuck working with an older server version that doesn't support events, but I would expect defining them is similar to STORED routines.

Comment: THANKSSSS ,it worked (y) i will accept the answer in 5 min

Comment: it's the delimiter most of the time

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're seeing  to do with the use of the semi-colon delimiter. you could change the delimiter but you only have one statement so you don't need the BEGIN...END block

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `money`
ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY  1 HOUR
DO
    DELETE FROM `money` WHERE `payed` = 'processing' AND `payed2` = 'processing';
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need `BEGIN` and `END`. Just write your query in the `DO` block. That should work.